# unable to change the color of header stlye in react native

Tags: react-native

I'm starting to learn react native and I'm trying to change the header color but when I run the app only the text color changed to white. And the terminal shows some warning. Are both of them related? Here are some screenshots of it.

```
 import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { setStatusBarBackgroundColor, StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import LoginScreen from './screens/LoginScreen';

const globalScreenOptions ={
  headerStyle: { BackgroundColor:"dodgerblue" },
  headerTitleStyle: {color: "white"},
  headerTinColor:"white",
};
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={globalScreenOptions} >
      <Stack.Screen name='Login' component={LoginScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOrP6.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kTsK.png)

Comment: Please post the code, not an image. Also, is it supposed to be headerTinColor?

Comment: BackgroundColor:"dodgerblue" should be backgroundColor:"dodgerblue" "b" should be in small case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This its working you must provide style on Stack.Screen

```
            <Stack.Screen options={{headerStyle:{backgroundColor:'dodgerblue'}}}name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
```